# Need a LAN Network Traffic Monitor web-tool

Tags: lan, network-monitoring, network-traffic

I've spent hours looking for a tool to monitor my LAN network.
My router is a TP-LINK TL-WR941N, and it provides a Statistics Page, which seems useful.

ROUTER STATISTICS:

[image]

However I need a webtool with some **graph** (references in KB/MB preferly), user-friendly, that runs through a port, so that **every PC has access to it and view the traffic of everyone**.

Does anything like this exists?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes close is [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/%20MRGG). This gives you images like the one below.
[image: MRTG Graph]

The only thing is that you have to run MRTG on a server, which reads the statistics over SNMP from the router. You can then expose these graphs using a webserver. The advantage of this approach is that it gives you a clear overview, and provides a historic view of the bandwidth usage over time. The disadvantage is that you have to use a webserver, and the statistics are not real-time.

Another possibility is that you install OpenWRT, which provides real-time monitoring. The advantage is that it provides detailed traffic statistics, even showing number of connections. The disadvantage is that you would have to reinstall your access point, and there is no history of bandwidth usage provided.

Comment: thanks for the data! no real-time because it doesn't refresh automatically? I'm reading that a .htaccess file is needed to force images to expire... Would I have to configure something in the router to send the SNMP messages to MRTG or it just knows what to do?... yeah, I though about another firmware, I know better how to install DD-WRT but I wanted to know if there was another option, and it seems there's not so many.

Comment: I have not needed to install a .htaccess to force that, most browsers will probably refresh properly.

However, the data itself is near-real-time. MRTG fetches data every minute or so, and it takes a few moments to process. So you get some indication, but it is not updating every second, like DD-WRT would.